# How can I disable save password popup in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium version 3.141.59 for Java and I would like to disable password popup while initializing the driver for Chrome and Firefox.

I am using the Options syntax since the DesiredCapabilities alternative is now deprecated. My code look like this, but it is not working:

- Firefox

```java
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("signon.rememberSignons", false);
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

- Chrome

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("credentials_enable_service", false);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

How can I add that option to the options object before creating the driver?

Answer (score 5):

Below are java code, which worked for me. I am using selenium 3.3.1 with selenium-chrome-driver 3.3.1 and Java 8.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```